# Failing Ceedling Test help: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'

Tags: arm, embedded, cmsis, ceedling

I have a C project with EMF32 with Simplicity Studio with Ceedling Test.

When performing test in Windows, I'm getting this error:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/ccaZBbw6.s: Assembler messages:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/ccaZBbw6.s:112: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/ccaZBbw6.s:136: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
ERROR: Shell command failed.
```

When performing test in Ubuntu with Github Actions, I'm getting this error:

```
/home/runner/work/Lib/GeckoSdk/v3.2/platform/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h: Assembler messages:
/home/runner/work/Lib/GeckoSdk/v3.2/platform/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h:882: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
/home/runner/work/Lib/GeckoSdk/v3.2/platform/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h:882: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
```

which points on this function on `cmsis_gcc.h` that the number of operands mismatch

```
/**
  \brief   Data Synchronization Barrier
  \details Acts as a special kind of Data Memory Barrier.
           It completes when all explicit memory accesses before this instruction complete.
 */
__STATIC_FORCEINLINE void __DSB(void)
{
  __ASM volatile ("dsb 0xF":::"memory");
}
```

But when runned in Mac OS, I'm not getting this error.

Comment: It might help if you showed the function that is being tested, and the test itself.